# Display empty form collection item in Symfony without using javascript

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I'm trying to display a form with a collection. The collection should display an empty sub-form. Due to the projects nature I can't rely on JavaScript to do so.

Googling didn't help and I does not seem to work by adding an empty entity to the collection field.

What I have so far:

```
public function indexAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $event = $em->getRepository('EventBundle:EventDynamicForm')->find($id);

    $entity = new Booking();
    $entity->addParticipant( new Participant() );
    $form   = $this->createForm(new BookingType(), $entity);

    return array(
        'event' => $event,
        'edit_form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

In BookingType.php buildForm()

```
$builder
    ->add('Participants', 'collection')
```

In the Twig template

```
{{ form_row(edit_form.Participants.0.companyName) }}
```

If I put the line $entity->addParticipant( new Participant() ); in indexAction() I get an error saying:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   Yanic\EventBundle\Entity\Participant. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to
>   "Yanic\EventBundle\Entity\Participant" or by adding a view transformer
>   that transforms an instance of class
>   Yanic\EventBundle\Entity\Participant to scalar, array or an instance
>   of \ArrayAccess.

If I delete the said line Twig complains:

> Method "0" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony-standard-2.1/src/Yanic/EventBundle/Resources/views/Booking/index.html.twig
>   at line 27

EDIT: The addParticipant is the default methos generated by the doctrine:generate:entities command

```
/**
 * Add Participants
 *
 * @param \Yanic\EventBundle\Entity\Participant $participants
 * @return Booking
 */
 public function addParticipant(\Yanic\EventBundle\Entity\Participant $participants)
 {
     $this->Participants[] = $participants;

     return $this;
 }
```

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but can't find the clue :-(

Comment: What is the content of `addParticipant()` function? Also, provide your `ParticipantType()`.

Comment: @ihsan I've updated my question with the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are a bit lost on Symfony2 form collection, though I think you already read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.
Here I will just emphasize the doc, help other SO readers, and exercise myself a bit on answering question.. :)

First, you must have at least two entities. In your case, `Booking` and `Participant`. In Booking entity, add the following. Because you use Doctrine, `Participant` must be wrapped in `ArrayCollection`.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Booking() {

    // ...

    protected $participants;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->participants = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getParticipants()
    {
        return $this->participants;
    }

    public function setParticipants(ArrayCollection $participants)
    {
        $this->participants = $participants;
    }
}
```

Second, your Participant entity could be anything. Just for example:

```
class Participant
{
    private $name;

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Third, your BookingType should contain collection of ParticipantType, something like this:

```
// ...
$builder->add('participants', 'collection', array('type' => new ParticipantType()));
```

Fourth, the ParticipantType is straightforward. According to my example before:

```
// ...
$builder->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true));
```

Last, in BookingController, add the necessary amount of Participant to create a collection.

```
// ...
$entity = new Booking();

$participant1 = new Participant();
$participant1->name = 'participant1';
$entity->getParticipants()->add($participant1); // add entry to ArrayCollection

$participant2 = new Participant();
$participant2->name = 'participant2';
$entity->getParticipants()->add($participant2); // add entry to ArrayCollection
```

Comment: Hi Ihsan... thanks for putting it in the right shape :-) I had it working already, but it's good to have the answer for others and also in case I forget (which can easily happen) :-)

Answer (score 0):

think you have to add here the type:

```
 ->add('Participants', 'collection', array('type' => 'YourParticipantType'));
```

Could you also paste in here the declaration of your addParticipant function from the model? Seems that there's something fishy too.

Comment: I've updated my question with the content of addParticipant()

Comment: type => 'YourParticipantType'... what should I put there... I tried putting `ParticipantType` and also the full namespace, but Symfony always says "Could not load type...."

Comment: Got it... I found the correct usage of 'type' in the Docs... its "new ParticipantType()"... now I've got another error... @user1452962 If you update your answer with the right usage of 'type' I'll accept it :-)